# Gulp. How to merge files without lines duplication

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I need to merge 2 files with gulp. Like

```
concat = require('gulp-concat')

gulp.src(['file1', 'file2'])
.pipe(concat('merge'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
```

But without lines duplication. So if two files contains same line, merge file needs to contain this line only once.

**file1**

```
lineA
lineB
lineC
```

**file2**

```
lineD
lineA
lineF
```

**merge**

```
lineA
lineB
lineC
lineD
lineF
```

Is there some plugin for this? Help please)

Comment: Hi, Could you not write a task in gulp which reads two files and generates one files with no duplicates, where it writes the merge content to a new file with no duplicates.

Comment: Cont'd previous comment,

Read files async and store each line in an object as key, where value is 1. So this way you only store a line if it has not been stored already. 

After reading all the files you go through the keys of the object and write to new file. Also, you can write to the new file every time you discover a new line it doesn't have to be at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a buffer mapper, here is an example with [map-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/map-stream):

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var map    = require('map-stream');

var uniqueFilterFn = function(item, idx, all) {
  return idx === all.indexOf(item);
};

gulp.src(['file1', 'file2'])
.pipe(concat('merge'))
.pipe(map(function(file, cb) {

  // convert file buffer into a string
  var contents = file.contents.toString();

  // split it by lines
  var lines = contents.split(/[\r\n]/);

  // apply the unique filter
  var uniqueLines = lines.filter(uniqueFilterFn);

  // join unique list into lines
  var output = uniqueLines.join('\n');

  // convert string back into buffer
  var buffer = new Buffer(output, 'binary');

  // replace the file contents
  file.contents = buffer;

  // continue
  return cb(null, file);
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
```